# Earning badges more than once

Tags: support

What happens say if u got 2 posts with >10000 views.  Do you get 2 famous question badges or 1?  It is said: Question with 10,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times under the description.

Answer (score 2):

When a badge's description says "This badge can be awarded multiple times", you will get one instance of that badge for each event that matches the criteria for which the badge is awarded. In this case, that means you get a Famous Question badge for each question you ask that has more than 10000 views.

Comment: so for example, I see a user like you with 2 gold badges.  Is it possible both are famous qns?

Comment: @XcoderX if you click on the profile, you should be able to see their badges they've earned (may not be possible on mobile app).

Comment: @XcoderX Note that those two gold badges are on meta; on main, David has [23 gold badges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/124/david-z?tab=badges), including e.g. [five Famous Question badges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question?userid=124). (For best results, see on the desktop site. On the mobile site / the iOS+android apps, your mileage may vary.)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not correct. Specific example: the "Revival" badge can be earned multiple times but the description merely states "Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring 2 or more ". I really would appreciate if each badge was clearly marked whether or not it could be obtained multiple times.